# How to iteratively plot different data as boxplots in seaborn (without them overlapping)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, boxplot

Is there a way to iteratively plot data using `seaborn`'s [`sns.boxplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) without having the boxplots overlap? (without combining datasets into a single [`pd.DataFrame()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html))

**Background**

Sometimes when comparing different (e.g. size/shape) datasets, a mutual comparison is often useful and can be made by binning the datasets by a different shared variable (via [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) and [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), as shown below).

Previously, I have iteratively plotted these "binned" data as boxplots on the same axis  by looping separate DataFrames using `matplotlib`'s [`ax.boxplot()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html) (by providing y axis location values as a `position` argument to to ensure boxplots don't overlap).

**Example**

Below is an simplified example that shows the overlapping plots in when using `sns.boxplot()`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import random
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get the tips dataset and select a subset as an example
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
variable_to_bin_by = 'tip'
binned_variable = 'total_bill'
df = tips[[binned_variable,  variable_to_bin_by] ]

# Create a second dataframe with different values and shape
df2 = pd.concat( [ df.copy() ] *5 )    
# Use psuedo random numbers to convey that df2 is different to df
scale = [ random.uniform(0,2) for i in range(len(df2[binned_variable])) ]  
df2[ binned_variable ] = df2[binned_variable].values * scale * 5
dfs = [ df, df2 ]

# Group the data by a list of bins
bins = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
for n, df in enumerate( dfs ):
    gdf = df.groupby( pd.cut(df[variable_to_bin_by].values, bins ) )
    data = [ i[1][binned_variable].values  for i in gdf]
    dfs[n] = pd.DataFrame( data, index = bins[:-1])

# Create an axis for both DataFrames to be plotted on
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Loop the DataFrames and plot
colors = ['red', 'black']    
for n in range(2):
    ax = sns.boxplot( data=dfs[n].T, ax=ax, width=0.2, orient='h', 
                      color=colors[n] )
plt.ylabel( variable_to_bin_by )
plt.xlabel( binned_variable )
plt.show()
```

[image: Over lapping boxplots]

**More detail**

I realise the simplified example above could resolved by combining the DataFrames and providing the `hue` argument to `sns.boxplot()`.

Updating the index of the DataFrames provide also doesn't help, as y values from the last DataFrame provided is then used.

Providing the `kwargs` argument (e.g. `kwargs={'positions': dfs[n].T.index}`) won't work as this raises a `TypeError`.

> TypeError: boxplot() got multiple values for keyword argument
>   'positions'

The setting `sns.boxplot()`'s `dodge` argument to `True` doesn't solve this.

Comment: you need to create plt settings in the loop, after before and after `sns.boxplot`

Comment: The usual strategy would indeed be to combine the data into a single dataframe. Why is this not an option here?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi, please could give the settings you recommend updating?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Indeed. I have updated the example following your comment to try and highlight that the DataFrames in this example differ in shape and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough, the "hack" that I proposed [earlier today in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48185587/1356000) could be applied here.

It complicates the code a bit because seaborn expects a long-form dataframe instead of a wide-form to use hue-nesting.

```
# Get the tips dataset and select a subset as an example
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
df = tips[['total_bill',   'tip'] ]

# Group the data by 
bins = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
gdf = df.groupby( pd.cut(df['tip'].values, bins ) )
data = [ i[1]['total_bill'].values  for i in gdf]
df = pd.DataFrame( data , index = bins[:-1]).T
dfm = df.melt() # create a long-form database
dfm.loc[:,'dummy'] = 'dummy'

# Create a second, slightly different, DataFrame
dfm2 = dfm.copy()
dfm2.value = dfm.value*2
dfs = [ dfm, dfm2 ]
colors = ['red', 'black']
hue_orders = [['dummy','other'], ['other','dummy']]

# Create an axis for both DataFrames to be plotted on
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Loop the DataFrames and plot
for n in range(2):
    ax = sns.boxplot( data=dfs[n], x='value', y='variable', hue='dummy', hue_order=hue_orders[n], ax=ax, width=0.2, orient='h', 
                      color=colors[n] )
ax.legend_.remove()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Diziet! Your example and then a [adding legend manually](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists) gives me exactly what I was after.