# twinx and sns.barplot seaborn are overlapping bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I would like to use `sns.seaborn` to display the `np.sum` and the `np.mean` on 2 different axes (with `ax2 = ax1.twinx()` I assume). The probem I have is that the graphs are overlapped and not readable.

Am I approaching the problem correctly?
What can I do to get those bars next to each other?

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
f, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, estimator=np.mean, ax=ax1)
sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, estimator=np.sum, ax=ax2, ci=None)
```

Thanks for your help

Larry

Comment: As usual on this site, you'll get more help if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please provide mockup data, in particular check out [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, I will fix it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be better off aggregating your data with `pandas` and then using the standard matplotlib `ax.bar()` function to plot the resulting dataframe.

If you insist on using seaborn, the following is somewhat of a "hackish" way of obtaining the desired result.

To move each bars slightly to the left or to the right, I create a dummy categorical column that I'm using for hue-nesting, and I use the `hue_order=` parameter to request one of the plot to be on the left, and the reverse order for the second bar-plot to be on the right.

```
# create a dummy categorical column with only one category
invoicedb.loc[:,'dummy'] = 'dummy'

f, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
sns.barplot(x="InvoiceMonth", y="TotalInvoice", hue='dummy', data=invoicedb, estimator = np.mean, ax = ax1, color = 'r', hue_order=['dummy','other'])
sns.barplot(x="InvoiceMonth", y="TotalInvoice", hue='dummy', data=invoicedb, estimator = np.sum, ci = None, ax = ax2, color = 'b', hue_order=['other','dummy'])
# hue-nesting automatically creates a legend that we need to remove by hand
ax1.legend_.remove()
ax2.legend_.remove()
```

Comment: I will consider a solution like that, Thank you Diziet Asahi